# Introducing predicates in Prolog

Tags: prolog

We start with an empty database and the following commands are given

`assert(q(a,b)),assertz(q(1,2)),asserta(q(foo,blug)).`

> What does now the database contain?
>
> What happens after the following commands?

`retract(q(1,2)),assertz((p(X):-h(X))).`

> Finally, what happens after the following command?

`retract(q(_,_)),fail.`

**MyAttempt**

I introduced the following commands in Prolog

`assert(q(a,b)).`

`assertz(q(1,2)).`

`asserta(q(foo,blug)).`

but it marked an error saying that `q` should be of `1` parameter and not `2`.

Could someone please help me? How can I fix this?  Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can not reproduce this error. If I run this in `swipl`, it works.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem really? I don't know what version I am using, but it marks an error. Also, the definition that I have in my notes says it's only 1 parameter

Comment: Are you sure you made no mistake with the parenthesis in the querying? I copied your queries and it worked (well I did not verify that the facts are in the "interpreter database", but there were no errors).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What querying? I doesn't even let me querying because it doesn't even compile. The 3 asserts are going to be in the text editor, no?

Comment: Ah, I did them interactively in Prolog's `swipl`. But in a file it makes no sense to do `asserta`'s, etc. as "naked expressions". Since `asserta(exp)` is equal to `exp` in the head of the file. You can only do these in the *body* of predicates.

Comment: If I write `main :- asserta(q(1,2)).` and in `swipl` query `main`, then it works.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The 3 predicates will be in the same rule?

Comment: not per se, point is that `asserta/1` and `assertz/1` calls need to be *in* a clause. Since it would be non-sensical to call these when *loading* the file.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do you know where can I find similar solved exercise like the one I posted? I am totally lost in this topic

Comment: You might need a directive: `:- dynamic(q/2).` to tell Prolog you intend to have a dynamic term in the database.

Comment: @lurker oh ok, I don't know what's that. I'll google it. Thanks

Comment: It's in the SWI Prolog documentation.

Comment: the use of the word "commands" suggests you are to issue these *commands* at the *prompt*. Then you can query the state of a predicate by using `listing(q)` or `listing(p)`. Just try it. Also try `retract(q(_,_)).` without the "`fail`".

Comment: @WillNess would you mind to take a look at my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fail` in `retract(q(_,_)),fail.` makes it loop until no more `q/2`s are left in the database.

How it works is, Prolog wants to prove a goal it is given; so when our goal ends with an explicit `fail`, that `fail` always fails so the overall goal fails too; but Prolog *wants to prove it* and so continues to try to prove it, so it "retries" any outstanding goals' choice-points still in place "above" that `fail`.

Simply put, it retries the `retract(q(_,_))` goal.

Each `retract(q(_,_))` goal retracts *one* instance of `q/2` from our <s>data</s> knowledge base. So with this *failure-driven loop*, they all are removed and the final result is still a failure.

In a pure setting only this result counts -- a goal's failure or success. But `assert` and `retract`-kind of predicates are called for their *side-effects*, not for their success or failure. Their *side* effect is, that they affect the state of our data base.

In fact, normally a failure-driven loop would look like

```
retract(q(_,_)),fail ; true.
```

to achieve the same effect, but *succeed* (instead of failing), to signal, well, *success* in achieving its intended effect.

Answer (score 0):

By reading theory we could conclude the following.

To the first question,

`q(foo,blug).`

`q(a,b).`

`q(1,2).`

To the second question,

`q(foo,blug).`

`q(a,b).`

`p(A):-h(A).`

To the third question, I think removes all the predicates `q`. I don't know what is the action of ',fail' here.

Comment: Feel free to modify my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @WillNess

Comment: you're welcome. I've moved my edit out into its own answer, as I should've done in the first place. :)

Comment: @WillNess oh ok. do you know about SLDNF-forest?

Comment: No. But post your question, someone will surely answer. :) thanks for the pointer BTW. Ah, I see you've asked and deleted it (Google found it for me). What is the book you show there?

Comment: @WillNess People from here told me to ask the question in other site:  https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97741/understanding-sldnf-forest